# How to host tomcat on default port (80)

Tags: linux, tomcat, web, port, administration

my tomcat web-application has been hosted on port 8080, it means i need to go for example: http://domain:8080/ to access my app, but its bad. How to make that i need go only http://domain/ ?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to edit server.xml (under your Tomcat's conf/ directory) find the <Connector> entry with protocol="HTTP/1.1" and change port="8080" to port="80".

However, you will need administrator or root access to do this, and there needs to be nothing else on the server that's already using port 80 (or at least nothing using the same IP number). You may need to add more information to your question to say what operating system you are using, and you may find this question is better asked on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) than here.

Comment: i had already tried and it didnt work - 404. I cheked, that 80 is clear, he was. I'm using Linux/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: If you get a 404 error, then you have correctly attached your application to port 80 (otherwise you wouldn't get any error at all except that the browser will fail to connect). Is it definitely Tomcat that is serving up the 404 error (it will tell you a Tomcat version at the bottom of the page if so), or could it be Apache or something else which is holding onto the port?